# Why does size of temp internet files folder exceed max folder size?

Tags: registry, temporary-files, special-folders

I am making a web page that detects the size of the "Temporary Internet Files" folder as well as the maximum size of that folder according to the registry. The code works fine, but with a surprising result: the actual size of the folder can exceed the maximum size set in the registry! Why? I thought that Windows or IE was supposed to automatically delete files once it reached that limit... Any explanation would be very helpful!